# Oracle 12 Client odbc empty TNS

Tags: odbc, oracle12c, tns

I have installed an oracle 12 Client on a windows 8 computer and on a windows 7 computer.
Using sqlplus I can connect to my database. Also the tnsping shows the right tns.
But when I try to set an odbc connection the TNS list is empty.

If I try to type the tns connection the test works, but when I try to launch my program from visual studio 2013 I get a general connection error.

I've already tried the fixes I could find on the internet (like checking that I have the 64 bit client and the 64 bit app, making a TNS_ADMIN environment variable set).
Mostly I'm wondering about the odbc problem.(this app is not using this type of connection, but I'm considering it - if I can be sure there are no problems).